# In PyTorch, How to COMPLETELY release gpu memory of a model after training and do other things

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch

When training, the model requires gradients and consumes much gpu memory, after training, I want to evaluate the model performance of different steps/epochs **in parallel(multi-processing)**, where each of the subprocess loads different parameters for the model without gradients. In order to spawn as many subprocesses as there could be, I want to **COMPLETELY** free the gpu memory occupied by the previous model (in training phase).

I've tried `del model` and `torch.empty_cache()` as many suggested, but the `nvidia-smi` still shows the gpu memory is not released, which will prevent me from creating as many evaluation subprocesses as expected (*raising the error of `CUDA out of memory`*).

So anyone can help me completely delete the model from gpu? In addition, I don't mind loading the model repeatedly in each subprocess because the model in training is far bigger than the model in evaluating. Or tell me why my proposal is not realistic.

Comment: This might not be the best way or the way you want, but you could just run a new script and load the model onto that script. If you stop the file that is running the gradients the gpu memory should clear then you can run a new script in a different file for evaluation.

Comment: This would be my last try, thank you anyway.